# Time derivative of total angular momentum in Dirac equation

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I would like to calculate the time derivative of the total angular momentum of a Dirac particle in an electromagnetic field $(\vec A, \phi)$:
$$\vec J = \vec r \times (\vec p - \frac{q}{c} \vec A) + \vec S$$
where $$\vec S = \frac{\hbar}{4i} (\vec \alpha \times \vec \alpha)$$

My approach so far is to differentiate each part directly as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d\vec J}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt} (\vec r \times (\vec p - \frac{q}{c} \vec A) + \vec S)\\
&= \frac{d\vec r}{dt} \times (\vec p - \frac{q}{c} \vec A) + \vec r \times q (\vec E + \vec \alpha \times \vec B) + \frac{d\vec S}{dt}\\
&= c\vec \alpha \times (\vec p - \frac{q}{c} \vec A) + \vec r \times q (\vec E + \vec \alpha \times \vec B) + \frac{d\vec S}{dt}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The end result is $$\vec M = \vec r \times q(\vec E + \vec \alpha \times \vec B)$$
which means that $$c\vec \alpha \times (\vec p - \frac{q}{c} \vec A) = - \frac{d\vec S}{dt}$$

Why can that be assumed?

Comment: The total angular momentum is not conserved in an external electromagnetic field so it cannot be assumed

Comment: I might have not made it clear enough, but the result is that the time derivative of the total angular momentum equals the torque $\vec M$. The remaining terms in the third to last line need to cancel each other, which is the condition in the last line.